# Is there Windows copy command that mimic Unix `cp -r` behavior?

Tags: windows, command-line, file-transfer, robocopy, xcopy

I don't know how to name this behavior vividly, just call it `loyalcopy`.

Two figures will illustrate it clearly.

[image: before copy]

I'd like to issue two commands to copy two filesystem nodes (regardless it is a file for a directory):

```
loyalcopy c:\libsrc\include     d:\temp\dest
loyalcopy c:\libsrc\mm_psfunc.h d:\temp\dest
```

and see result like this:

[image: after copy]

What actual Windows commands can achieve this effect? I tried *xcopy* and *robocopy*, and they do not work as desired. For example, `xcopy c:\libsrc\include d:\temp\dest /s` would copy contents **inside** `include`, not creating a mirrored `include` directory in destination folder.

On Unix, I know I can replace `loyalcopy` with `cp -r` to achieve desired result. But is there Windows equivalent of it? Better to have Windows stock commands, no third-party software involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just run `cp -r c:\libsrc\include d:\temp\dest` in PowerShell. It'll work as expected. It's actually the alias to

```
Copy-Item -Recurse -Path c:\libsrc\include -Destination d:\temp\dest
```

---

With [xcopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy) or [robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) you'll need to specify the folder name in the destination in order for it to be created

```
robocopy /E c:\libsrc\include d:\temp\dest\include
xcopy /E /I /H c:\libsrc\include d:\temp\dest\include
```

> `/I:` If *Source* is a directory or contains wildcards and *Destination* does not exist, `xcopy` assumes *Destination* specifies a directory name and creates a new directory. Then, `xcopy` copies all specified files into the new directory. By default, `xcopy` prompts you to specify whether *Destination* is a file or a directory.
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy

To get help on any classic Windows tools just use `/?`, for example `xcopy /?`, `robocopy /?`. Note that [xcopy has been deprecated](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) and may be removed in the future

Comment: Thank you for the points. `cp -r` in Powershell works as expected. `xcopy /i` is still undesired, because we users have to explicitly pass `/I` when copying  `c:\libsrc\include` but omit `/I` when copying `c:\libsrc\mm_psfunc.h`. That is extra burden.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
xcopy /h /e /i "c:\libsrc\include\" "d:\temp\dest\include\"
xcopy /h /e /i "c:\libsrc\mm_psfunc.h" "d:\temp\dest\mm_psfunc.h"
```

Comment: No luck. `0 File(s) copied`. xcopy seems to apply wildcards on **filenames**, never on folder names.

Comment: @Jimm Chen please see updated answer

Comment: See xcopy /? for all flags. You may want to add /O as well to copy also file-permissions and owners ship information. If you don't ALL destination folders/files will inherit their permissions from the parent folder. "/O" may need admin-rights in order to work properly though.